# Sort on Month name in crosstab report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a crosstab report which displays months as rows. When i run the report the rows start with aug and go on in ascending order. How can i sort this report based on our calender like jan, feb,march .....

i tried to add under textField expression the following code

```
<textfieldexpression class="java.lang.String">
    (
        $V{Month}.equals("JAN-15") ? "Jan" : 
        $V{Month}.equals("FEB-15") ? "Feb" :
        $V{Month}.equals("MAR-15") ? "Mar" :
        $V{Month}.equals("APR-15") ? "Apr" :
        $V{Month}.equals("MAY-15") ? "May" :
        $V{Month}.equals("JUN-15") ? "Jun" :
        $V{Month}.equals("JUL-15") ? "Jul" :
        $V{Month}.equals("AUG-15") ? "Aug" :
        $V{Month}.equals("SEP-15") ? "Sep" :
        $V{Month}.equals("OCT-15") ? "Oct" : 
        $V{Month}.equals("NOV-15") ? "Nov" : "Dec"
    )
</textfieldexpression>
```

but it returns with the same thing (not sorted).

Comment: you have to fetch a new column which returns the sequence no of the month like 01, 02, 03.. etc.. and based on this you can define your sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do ordering through your query. You can make use of the pre-defined functions.

Below is the query that I used to sort for your requirement. **I am using Amazon Redshift**

```
select * from(
 select to_char(sysdate,'Mon-YY') month_value
 union all 
 select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'Mon-YY') 
 union all
 select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-3),'Mon-YY') 
 union all
 select to_char(add_months(sysdate,1),'Mon-YY') )
order by date_part(month,to_date(date1,'Mon-YY'))
```

In the **order by** clause, I have **converted the string format of date to datatype date** and then take the **month part for ordering**.

Hope this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

what i do is edit the query to be (TO_CHAR(REQUEST_TIMESTAMP, 'MM') "REQUESTDATE") to return the date just like 01,02,03,.... 
then i put in the expression for requestdate header

(

---

```
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "01" ? "Jan" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "02" ? "Feb" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "03" ? "Mar" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "04" ? "Apr" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "05" ? "May" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "06" ? "Jun" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "07" ? "Jul" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "08" ? "Aug" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "09" ? "Sep" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "10" ? "Oct" :
$V{REQUESTDATE}.intern() == "11" ? "Nov" : "Dec" )
```

and now the report is sorted.